# Which parts of a Ruby DSL will I need to build by hand?

Tags: ruby, domain-driven-design, jruby, dsl

If I want to build a DSL in Ruby 1.9 or JRuby, will I need to do any of these stages by hand:

- Lexing
- Interpretation
- Parsing
- Just-in-time compilation

Obviously, being a programmer, I don't like to write actual code as much as I can get away with, so I'm hoping none of these steps require manual labor :)

Answer (score 6):

It's all done using metaprogramming. You don't have to do any of the things you list. Jamis Buck has a nice blog post on [Writing Domain Specific Languages](http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2006/4/20/writing-domain-specific-languages/) using Ruby.

Answer (score 6):

It depends on what you want. For writing an internal(read: uses ruby syntax) DSL, it is just ruby all the way down. If you want to build a DSL that doesn't use ruby syntax you could look at the treetop gem.

Jeremy Mcanally has a [pretty good presentation about DSLs](http://mwrc2009.confreaks.com/13-mar-2009-18-10-jive-talkin-dsl-design-and-construction-jeremy-mcanally.html). He goes through both external and internal DSL stuff.

Comment: I think the pretty good presentation is now moved here: [Jive Talkin': DSL Design and Construction](http://www.confreaks.com/videos/57-mwrc2009-jive-talkin-dsl-design-and-construction)